# How to configure module in Karma tests with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-mock

I have a test that uses this module **bxAuth** module, and I require it like this:

```
beforeEach(module('bxAuth'));
```

This module must be configured in order to work. So I have a test that expect errors when module is not configured, and tests that check if module services work as expected after configuration (each scenario has its own describe block).

However, if I configure the module like this (only in second describe block):

```
angular.module('bxAuth').config(ConfigureAuth);
```

my module is configured in all describe blocks, so basically it is always configured.

Here is a complete code:

```
describe('not configured bxAuth module', function() {

    beforeEach(module('bxAuth'));

    var bxAuth;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_bxAuth_) {
        bxAuth = _bxAuth_;
    }));

    it('should throw exception without cofiguration', function () {
        expect(bxAuth.authenticate).toThrow(); // **this expectation fails**
    });
});

describe('configured bxAuth module', function () {

    beforeEach(module('bxAuth'));

    var bxAuth;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_bxAuth_) {
        bxAuth = _bxAuth_;
    }));

    angular.module('bxAuth').config(ConfigureAuth);

    function ConfigureAuth(bxAuthProvider) {

        bxAuthProvider.config.authenticate = function (username, password) {

            var deferred = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$q').defer();

            /* replace with real authentication call */
            deferred.resolve({
                id: 1234,
                name: 'John Doe',
                roles: ['ROLE1', 'ROLE2']
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        } 
    }

    it('should not throw exception with cofiguration', function () {
        expect(bxAuth.authenticate).not.toThrow();
    });

});
```